# why python does not send anything with sockets? (basic sockets)

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, server, udp, client

As you can see in images below i cannot reciveve anything from client and server keeps waiting! I have tried it without firewall and no result.. :(

[cmd info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDAAd.png)
**Client**

```
import socket

sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

sock1.sendto("HOLA",('192.168.0.159',25585))

sock1.close()
del sock1
```

**Server**

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


sock.bind(('0.0.0.0',25585))

while True:
    data , c = sock.recvfrom(1024);
    print data

sock.close()
del sock
```

Comment: Looks ok to me, is the ipv4 address above correct? Have you tried using localhost (or 127.0.0.1) instead of the ipv4 address?

Comment: did you run the server script before the client script ?

Comment: @SPSP yes I have and does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client and your server are not connected. Try this:

**client**:

```
import socket

sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock1.connect(('192.168.0.159',25585))
sock1.sendto("HOLA",('192.168.0.159',25585))
sock1.close()
del sock1
```

Your **server** code is good

Otherwise UDP sockets are mostly known for packets dropping

Comment: I don't think connect is necessary in this case, does sendto() not automatically bind the socket to a suitable address if it's unbound?

Comment: @GinésDíaz Have you tried this code localy ? I mean run these scripts on the same os, connect the client to the 'localhost' ip?

Comment: @SPSP yes I've tried, this is strange , I think it is as os bug, I changed to linux (Solus operative system) and here seems to work. By the way, thank you all of you for answer! And sorry if Im a bit late.